# How can I access all child components of some type from a directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I've looked on a number of different threads on this, but still haven't found anything that works for me.  The closest thing that I could find seems to have been deprecated a long time ago: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8277

Basically, I'm working with a number of 3rd party components that aren't playing nicely together out of the box, so I set out to write a directive that I can attach to one and handle some custom logic.  The layout looks something like this:

```
<splitter myDirective>
    <split-panel>
        <my-component-1>
            <div>
                <pivot-grid></pivot-grid>
            </div>
        </my-component-1>
    </split-panel>
    <split-panel>
        <my-component-2>
            <div>
                <pivot-grid></pivot-grid>
            </div>
        </my-component-2>
    </split-panel>
</splitter>
```

The splitter allows for resizing at run-time.  Within my directive, I have access to the splitter component and its `ElementRef`.  What I'm currently doing is digging through the `children` recursively on the `ElementRef.nativeElement` and then setting the height on my `PivotGridComponent` using `Renderer2`.  However, the problem is that there's a caveat to the 3rd party `PivotGridComponent` in that I have to set the `height` property of the *component* itself or I don't have a scroll bar.

I've tried `@ViewChildren`, `@ContentChildren`, `@host() @self() @optional()` and none of these are able to grab my underlying `PivotGridComponent`.  I would've just put `@ViewChildren` in the splitter component itself, but that's also a 3rd party component, so it's not an option.  It also doesn't seem possible to navigate the component tree in the same way that I am navigating the `ElementRef` tree.

How can I get access to the component from the directive? I'm guessing that it's no longer possible to get the component from the `ElementRef` as the GitHub issue I linked seems to indicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@ContentChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) to retrieve children components from higher component / directive. Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will emit a new value.

Here's an example:

```js
@ContentChildren(SplitPanelComponent) public splitPanelComponents: QueryList<SplitPanelComponent>;
```

You can use it in your directive or in your `Splitter` component (where you're applying the directive on) and pass it to the directive.

If you want a more concrete example, you can take a look at [a code example of my library](https://github.com/biig-io/ngx-tabset/blob/master/src/ngx-tabset/src/components/tab-set.ts#L28) where I'm also using `@ContentChildren`.

Working example **[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejxfxv)**.

Comment: I've mentioned that I tried `@ContentChildren` already and it does not work.  I didn't realize this earlier, but `@ViewChild` is scoped to the component that it's on, so it wouldn't work with nested components, and I'm assuming `@ContentChildren` has a similar limitation.  I've updated the code example to better illustrate my hierarchy. I also want to avoid having the directive on `<my-component>`, since there's a lot of variations and it's simply not scalable to know exactly which ones need the directive at that level.  Every splitter will have a grid, but not every grid will be in a splitter

Comment: Oh right, sorry I didn't see it since I was also writing at the same time. Yes I understand. So can't you put the `@ContentChildren()` inside the root component `<splitter>` and pass a `public` property containing the list to `myDirective` like `<splitter myDirective="childrenComponentList">`? I tested it and I agree with you it works well on `@Component`s but not in `@Directive`s

Comment: A few problems with that.  `splitter` is a 3rd party component.  Even if you set it up where you can pass in a variable to the directive, it doesn't work since the look-up for `@ContentChildren` is scoped to the component that it's on and doesn't dig into child components.  Even if it did, it doesn't seem like a clean solution in the sense that you have to modify the parent component just to use the directive.

Comment: I made an example with `@ContentChildren` in a directive since I can't get how it can't work... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejxfxv let me know if it helps you. (you have to check your console and look into `_results`)

Comment: I updated your example to better reflect my file structure, which does not work. Note the additional wrapper component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fby6iw

Comment: In any case, I have made a temporary workaround with the addition of another directive for the pivot-grid component, as well as a registry service so that I can just save it by id and look it up.  This way, I don't have to have logic to look up the opposite direction and the types that I need to add a directive on can be easily found by just searching.  It's not the solution I wanted, but it works.  I'd still be interested if my original question has a solution, though.